# Скомпилировать код в ехе python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Я пытаюсь скомпилировать код в ехе я ввожу:
pyinstaller --onefile instagener.py
Ошибка:
C:\Users\Никитос>pyinstaller --onefile instagener.py
File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xed' in file C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Answer (score 0):

Смени место хранения папки с пользователя **Никитос** в другое место, надо чтобы путь состоял только из англ. букв. Если ошибка в этом, то **отметь галочкой** этот ответ как "Помогло"

Comment: не помогло ((((

Comment: pyinstaller --onefile instagener.py да? не надо же прописыть путь

Comment: Перейти в консоли в директорию, где лежит instagener.py и запускать оттуда:
pyinstaller -F instagener.py

Comment: ошибка тоже самая

Comment: я щяс увидел что у меня pyinstaller получается в русском пути по ошибке
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xed' in file C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Comment: Это критично????